# wso2is session timeout - invalid timestamp?

Tags: session, wso2-identity-server

we have upgraded from WSO2 IS 5.0.0.SP1 to WSO2IS 5.1.0 and we're trying to fix the session expiration. Seems the users is logged in for long time.

On the logon screen we have the rememberMe checked by default (we want users to be persistent for approx 14h = 840m)

What I see is multiple timeout parameters in the identity.xml:

```
    <SessionDataPersist>
        <Enable>true</Enable>
        <Temporary>false</Temporary>
        <SessionDataCleanUp>
            <Enable>true</Enable>
            <CleanUpTimeout>841</CleanUpTimeout>
            <CleanUpPeriod>30</CleanUpPeriod>
        </SessionDataCleanUp>
        <OperationDataCleanUp>
            <Enable>true</Enable>
            <CleanUpPeriod>30</CleanUpPeriod>
        </OperationDataCleanUp>
    </SessionDataPersist>
</JDBCPersistenceManager>
```

...

```
<TimeConfig>
    <SessionIdleTimeout>840</SessionIdleTimeout>
    <RememberMeTimeout>840</RememberMeTimeout>
</TimeConfig>
```

...

```
    <PersistanceCacheTimeout>900</PersistanceCacheTimeout>
    <SessionIndexCacheTimeout>900</SessionIndexCacheTimeout>
```

but seems the user is logged in even next day (24h)

Now checking the database for the session timeout we see the time_created is even placed far in future (3.5 days).

```
select  session_id , session_type, time_created, operation, tenant_id from idn_auth_session_store where session_id='8d761e3d-c2c8-4a50-b58f-dc20822a0000'

8d761e3d-c2c8-4a50-b58f-dc20822a0000 | SAMLSSOSessionIndexCache | 1467171230156905138 | STORE     |         0
```

Seems 1467171230156905138  is Wed, 29 Jun 2016 03:33:50 GMT

question is - has the time_created used as the expiration timestamp or is it somewhere wrongly converted? If it is used as the expiration date - where is it really configured?

Edit:

what I see from the code the value is (cannot we just use a simple ms timestamp?):

```
currentStandardNano = currentStandardNano + (currentSystemNano - FrameworkServiceDataHolder.getInstance().getNanoTimeReference());
```

this effectively move the timestamp in future for the value of the server's uptime. Is there a reason for it?

Thank you for any insight

Comment: we "patched" the authentication framework (from the source code) and store the direct nano timestamp, looks working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was identified as an issue in Identity server 5.1.0 and has been fixed for future releases. This has been discussed [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/pull/1744).